# Integrating Facebook and example.com

Tags: facebook

I'm creating web site where you can add idea and comment it. Last week I have been looking for Facebook integration. So you can post idea from Facebook or Example.com. You should also be able to comment ideas from Facebook and Example.com. Two interfaces, one result. Is that possible? And is the Facebook application only solution? What about Facebook group wall?

-- UPDATE

I have Facebook and Example.com. I would like to have full integration between those. Messages and comments sent from Facebook shows on Example.com and vice versa.

Comment: The question isn't descriptve enough!

Comment: I'm sorry about bad question. I have updated it and tried to add better description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Yes.

> And is the Facebook application only solution?

If you are trying to connect with Facebook, then yes.

> What about Facebook group wall?

Not sure what you mean by that.